# Purifying Things That Can Not Be Cleaned With Water

Tags: fiqh, sunnah, wudu, taharah

How Can I Purify Books Pages If Semen/Sperm Or Urine Fall On Them?
I Mean, How Can I Purify Things That Can Not Be Cleaned Or Purified By Water?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing which has been made a substitute of water in most of the cases if "**mud / soil**".

There are many places where we can find this. E.g. Qur'an in the Verse talking about Tayammam, Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) reported to be praying on the ground cleaned by pure mud etc.

So, I wish to conclude that things where water cannot be used, cleaning / purifying them with clean mud should be the best alternative.

Comment: I reckon the light of the Sun can be investigated as another cleaner as well as what you illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

First displace the unclean material with everything, but make sure that it doesn't exist anymore on that material. Then expose it to the direct sunshine(even not from behind a curtain or cloud) to make it dry. be sure that there is no wind and only the sun makes it dry.

If your material has two surfaces, make sure that both of them are exposed simultaneously. otherwise the surface which has been in front of the sun would be clean and the other surfaces wouldn't be clean or purified.

Comment: what you remarked looks true. Of course, you'd better try to submit at least one reference in your answer (s) in order to make it more creditable and more attractive. Meanwhile, it that case, you'll obtain more reputation as well. (as I saw one of your answer which was presented a reference ... Well done mate. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You very much.Will not be it very difficult for me, cleaning many books pages?I am thinking about it, it makes me mad!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the reference, but I remember right, it is in the dissertation of Mr.Makarem Shirazi.